# jQuery - Como remover linha da tabela criada dinamicamente?

Tags: jquery

Estou iniciando os estudos em jQuery e tenho a seguinte dúvida:

Tenho uma tabela criada em HTML. Esta tabela contém apenas uma linha com `th`'s. Os registros são inseridos por jQuery. Através de interação com o usuário, os dados são obtidos e salvos em variáveis, depois acrescentados à tabela com `append`:

```
$("table").append("<tr><td>" + nome + "</td><td>" + quantidade +
"</td><td>" + valor + "</td><td>" + dataFormatada + "</td><td>" +
acoes + "</td></tr>");
```

Até aqui, tudo funciona corretamente e consigo inserir todos os registros.

A variável ações foi definida da seguinte forma:

```
var acoes = "<a href='#' class='exclui'>Excluir</a> <a href='#' class='cor'>Mudar Cor</a>";
```

Ou seja, eu gostaria que fosse permitido excluir e alterar a cor de cada registro. Para a primeira parte, já tentei `hide`, `remove` e o código abaixo, mas nada funcionou:

```
$(".exclui").click(function() {
    //$(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Imagino que seja simples, mas não consegui. Alguém pode me ajudar? Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É necessário usar [EventDelegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), ou seja, o handler do evento fica em algum elemento pai dos elementos que vão ser inseridos futuramente. Dessa maneira quando o elemento for inserido e ocorrer um evento nele, este elemento propaga pra os pais até chegar no handler.

O jQuery já faz isso com o método [`jQuery.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

Exemplo:

```js
$("#tabela").on('click', '.exclui', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});


// Apenas insere <tr> dinamicamente para demonstração
var $tbody = $('#tabela').find('tbody');
$('#add-tr').on('click', function() {
    $tbody.append(`
      <tr>
        <td>Valor 1</td>
        <td>Valor 2</td>
        <td><button class="exclui">X</button></td>
      </tr>
    `);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="add-tr">Adiciona linha</button>

<table id="tabela">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Campo 1</th>
      <th>Campo 2</th>
      <th>Campo 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Obrigado! Era um simples detalhe. Sua solução parece mais elegante. Eu resolvi assim: `$(document).on('click', '.exclui', function() { $(this).parent().parent().remove(); });`

Comment: Acho que seria bom adicionar este handler à tabela (se ela não for adicionada dinamicamente também).. É uma boa pratica não adicionar handlers ao body ou document.

Comment: Se a solução te ajudou marque como correta. Assim que cair nessa página vinda do Google já acha mais facilmente a resposta. ;)

Comment: Eu sei, brother. Só dentro de 2 minutos... mas quanto a adicionar à tabela, você diz trocar document por "table"? Se for isso, só se já estiver dentro do ambiente `document` (o que não era o caso). ;)

Comment: Quando eu uso para remover `<tr>`s eu adiciono um `id` na tabela e uso `$('#minha-tabela')` no `on()`... assim a responsabilidade fica bem separada

Comment: A resposta vai ficar mais completa se eu adicionar fiddle.. calma aí